# Does $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^2)^\alpha}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm wondering when the integral 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^2)^\alpha}
$$
converges for the real number $\alpha$.

Comment: $ \alpha \gt 0 $ would be my guess.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Would you provide a proof for it?

Comment: The given integral can be written as $$ 2 \int_{0}^\infty \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^\alpha} $$. After that, you can get hints from this question -> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82597/improper-integrals-convergent-or-divergent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral is evaluated in terms of the Gamma function as follows

$${\frac {\sqrt {\pi }\Gamma  \left( -1/2+\alpha \right) }{\Gamma 
 \left( \alpha \right) }}
$$

Then $\alpha >1/2$ is domain with convergence.  When $\alpha =1/2$ the integral does not converge.  When $-1/2 + \alpha = -n$ where $n$ is a positive integer, the integral does not converge.

Do you agree?

Answer (score 4):

**Outline:** Use *Comparison*. Break up into two parts at $0$. By symmetry the two integrals both exist or both fail to exist, and if they exist they have the same value.

Since our function is nicely behaved on the interval $[-1,1]$, we only need to worry about $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^\alpha}\,dx$.

For $\alpha \gt 1/2$, we have convergence, by comparison with $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{2\alpha}}\,dx$.

If $\alpha\le 1/2$, we have divergence. For in the interval from $1$ to $\infty$, we have $(1+x^2)^\alpha \le (2x^2)^\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{}$
\begin{align}
&\mbox{When}\ \verts{x}\to\infty,\ \mbox{the integrand}\ \sim x^{-2\alpha}
\\[3mm]&\mbox{Its antiderivative}\ \sim x^{-2\alpha + 1}
\\[3mm]&\mbox{Convergengence requires}\ -2\,\Re\pars{\alpha} + 1 < 0
\end{align}

> It converges whenever $\ds{\color{#66f}{\large\Re\pars{\alpha} > \half}}$.

Comment: Dear @Felix Marin, Could you please explain how you got the condition $-2\Re({\alpha}) + 1 < 0$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for large $x$

$$ \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^\alpha} \sim \frac{1}{x^{2\alpha}} $$

Now check for what values of alpha the last integrand converge.